# Work with an object in multiple windows

Tags: c++, qt5

I want make a widget-based program with multiple windows. Actually, first I wrote a console application with generic C++ (without qt) and now I want make a GUI for that. So I have a "Client" class that can connect to server and work with console. Now I want to have a window to connect server, then a window to register or login and then a user panel to work with program (for logged in user).
The problem is how can I use an instance of "Client" class made by "connect server" window in other windows (login window, user panel, ...)?

Consider this scenario:
when program starts, a window will appear. User should enter server info and click "Connect" button. After that if the connection established, Client object will make and login window will appear. So where should I make Client and how can I pass it to other windows or use it in main.cpp file?

Comment: Do you want a *single* instance of the client object (a.k.a. *Singleton*)?  Or, would refactoring the class declaration and definition out of your window class suffice?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews  i think it would be better if client class be out of all windows. but i'm not sure!